# FTP Error for transferring the file

Tags: java, ftp

I am trying to run the following code for FTP in java but i am getting error
please help me identify it

```
public class FTPUploadFileDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String server = "localhost";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "username";
    String pass = "password";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
        File firstLocalFile = new File("C:/Users/un/workspace/Test.txt");

        String firstRemoteFile = "t1.txt";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

        System.out.println("Start uploading first file");
        boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        if (done) {
            System.out.println("The first file is uploaded successfully.");
        }


        File secondLocalFile = new File("C:/Users/un/workspace/Test.txt");
        String secondRemoteFile = "t2.txt";
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(secondLocalFile);


        OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile);
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
        int read = 0;

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

        boolean completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
        if (completed) {
            System.out.println("The second file is uploaded successfully.");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

The above program is showing following error :

Error: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Please guide me how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got this error message on `ftpClient.connect(server, port);` that means your ftp server is not correctly configured and is not accepting local connexion ; is your FTP server local or is it for this example ?

Comment: my ftp server is local, i am trying to transfer it locally within my system first,thats why i have written localhost,

Comment: So you should test your FTP server configuration first. Try to connect to it with a FTP client (like Filezilla, or event your OS shell if includes FTP protocol) in order to test it. If it doesn't work, you must modify the FTP server configuration to allow local connexion (or at least connexion). In order to test, you should specify very simple user name and password to connect to your FTP server ("username" and "password" as mentioned in your first post could be a good idea if you gave us fake credentials)

Comment: Thanks for reply but i already tried this one, filezilla, i provided hostname as "localhost" and user name password of my account, but it gives following error : Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server", trying next addres

Comment: please tell how to configure..

Comment: That depends of the software you use as FTP server. Under Windows or Linux ? What suite ?

Comment: ok, thanks  a lot, my problem is solved after configuring the ftp server onto my local machine